# Оценка сложности алгоритма

Tags: алгоритм, рекурсия, сложность

Предположим, у меня есть дерево. Передо мной стоит задача: найти самый глубокий лист, учитывая его корень. Вот псевдокод:

```
heightFunc(elem)
   height = 1;
   for all children c in elem:
     height = max(height, 1 + heightFunc(c));
 return height;
```

Понятно, что он сначала складывает в стек инфу,а потом достает. Но какая сложность у этого алгоритма? O(n)? O(log n)? И как вооще можно это оценивать?

Comment: но разве рекурсия не должна работать быстрее за счет использования стека? я думаю в худшм случае O(n)

Comment: не должна. У рекурсии в общем случае никакого стека нет

Comment: Вы проверяете все листья, так что никак не меньше O(n). Но вроде бы и не больше...

Comment: @Эникейщик первый раз слышу что рекурсия работает без использования стека в памяти

Comment: что вы в данном случае понимаете под стеком?

Comment: @Эникейщик когда рекурсивный метод вызывает самого себя, новым локальным переменным параметрам выделяется место в стеке и код метода выполняется с этими новы­ми исходными значениями. Типа, относительно самого себя. Только стек выделяемый компидятором, а не та структура которую мы ручками слепили. Обычно же есть стек и куча, в стеке хранятся ссылки, он меньше кучи, а в куче значения переменных, отсюда вероятность его переполнения при частых вызовах рекурсии. В предыдущей версии майнкрафта StackOverflowError вылетал когда делаешь чтото на кузнечной фигне))))))))))))))))))))))))

Comment: Ну так выполняется же заново. И если у вас рекурсивная функция f(n) вызывает f(n-1), а та вызывает f(n-1-1), то все будет вычисляться до самого конца, несмотря на то, что при предыдущем вызове f(n-1) f(n-1-1) уже вычислялось. А при вызове f(n+1) вся эта цепь повторных вычислений пойдет еще один раз. Никакого "работать быстрее" тут нет.

Comment: Но на самом деле я в своем первом комментарии немного перепутал и под стеком подразумевал мемоизацию :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Алгоритм работает за линейное время O(n).

Каждый узел посещается один раз, т.к. дерево -  у узла единственный родитель, два раза в один узел не заходим

---

Деревья бывают чёрно-красными, но само по себе это не поможет. А вот если в узлах хранить дополнительную информацию о высоте поддерева (т.н. augmented деревья (дополненные)), то за O(1) можно узнавать высоту дерева, если обновлять высоты в процессе изменения структуры (за O(logn) в случае сбалансированных деревьев)

Comment: хм, а если дерево будет черно-белым? можно так сэкономить время?

Comment: В ответ добавил.